# How to derive a general formula for this problem? (pairs of people seated around a table)

Tags: combinatorics

> $N$ people attend a dinner party and sit round a circular table.Each
>   person knows only the people sitting immediately next to him and has
>   to be introduced to everyone else.If the total number of pairs of
>   people introduced to each other is $20$,then what is the value of $N$?

Is this a form of any well known problem?I could only of think of a brute-force solution,however I am inquisitive to know how to solve this for any number of pairs in an efficient manner.

**ADDED**:It seems like I have understood the pattern,for any $N$ the number of pairs of introduction is given by $(N-3)+(N-3)+(N-3)-1+(N-3)-2+\cdots+2+1$ by using this idea the solution of the above problem should be $N=8$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each person is introduced to $N-3$ others.  As there are $N$ people, that would make $N(N-3)$ introductions, but each has been counted twice-once from each side.  So we have 20=$\frac{N(N-3)}{2}$, which has roots $8, -5$.

Comment: I did the same in a bit different way:$ 20 = 1+2+3+\cdots+(N-3)+(N-3)\Rightarrow (N-8)(N+5)=0$... hence the answer.

Comment: $+1$ and accepted.Reading your answer makes me feel a bit silly:P,I generated answers for first few $N$'s and tried to identify the pattern but all I am supposed to do just to think reasonably!

Comment: @FoolForMath:  I don't see how you take the sum to $(N-8)(N+5)$-the sum from $1$ to $N-3$ is $(N-2)(N-3)/2$ and adding the last $N+3$ takes us to $N(N-3)/2$.  The idea of counting each intro works sometimes, but here it is a bit hard to convince yourself you have the endgame right.

Comment: Okay,so $$1+2+3+\cdots+(N-3)+(N-3)=20 \implies\frac{N(N-3)}{2}=20 \implies$$
$$N^2-3N-40=0 \implies(N-8)(N-5)=0$$ (Hoping  I haven't committed any mistake in algebra!
)

Comment: @FoolForMath:  I was looking a step earlier.  You are right.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be the number of introductions.

Suppose that *everyone* must be introduced to everyone else.  Do this as follows.
(i) Everyone is introduced to her **left** neighbour ($N$ introductions);
(ii) Every pair of non-neighbours is introduced ($x$ introductions).

It follows that
$$\binom{N}{2}=N+x,\qquad\text{and therefore}\qquad x=\binom{N}{2}-N=\frac{N^2-3N}{2}.$$

Now we solve the equation
$$\frac{N^2-3N}{2}=20.$$
The only admissible solution is $N=8$.

Answer (score 0):

$nC2 - n = 20$

$n(n - 1)/2 - n = 20$

$n(n - 1) - 2n = 40$

$n^2 - 3n - 40 = 0$
$n^2 - 8n + 5n - 40 = 0$
$n(n - 8) + 5(n - 8) = 0$

$(n - 8)(n + 5) = 0$

$n = 8$ or $n = -5$

now n is positive and greater than $3$ ($3$ people needs no introduction) , so we take $n = 8$

Comment: For 4 people around a table we have

4c2 -4 = 2

i.e. 2 introductions.

Comment: An introduction involves 2 person. nC2 is the number of introductions among n people taken 2 at a time.

Comment: An introduction involves 2 person. nC2 is the number of introductions among n people taken 2 at a time.
Here (A introduced to B) and (B introduced to A) is the same introduction but counted twice in nC2. That is in all n introductions have been counted twice as every one needs an introduction if n > 3. To eliminate these n false introductions we subtract n from nC2.

Answer (score 0):

Total introductions needed(if nobody knows anyone)=$n\choose 2$; but since a person knows the person next to him, therefore introductions needed=${n\choose 2}-n$ which is given to be $20\implies \frac{n(n-1)}{2} - n=20\implies n^2-3n-40=0\implies n=8$.